# How to setup React Router <Link> inside a Datatables.net Cell?

Tags: reactjs, datatables, react-router

I have a datatables table (https://datatables.net) initialized like this:

```
 $('#example').DataTable({
 data: data,
 columns: [{
             title: "Database ID",
             data: 'database_id',
             render: function (data, type, row) {
                       return '<NavLink to="/shop">'+ data +'</NavLink>';
                    }
            }]
 });
```

The NavLink that i have in the code is supposed to render a database cell as a clickable link because of React-Router (This whole function is inside a React component), but the link is not rendering when i run the code.

What i ultimately want is the ability to click on a database cell that will take me to another component by routing into a link like "/shop/id" but i am stuck in it for a long time. Help!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and below solution is working for me.

1. You can directly add **anchor tag with href** to the path where you want to route upon on the click. But, it will reload your application.

   To avoid reloading of the application, try below solution.
2. When you're initializing the columns dynamically, you can add below code for the column where you want to have a link.

```
fnCreatedCell: (nTd, data) => ReactDOM.render(
                            <a
                                onClick={() => handletableclick(data, props)}>
                                {data}
                            </a>, nTd)
```

Add handletableclick() function/method in your file to handle click event and programmatically through history push the path where you want to route upon the click

```
function handletableclick(data, props) {
     props.history.push("/pathToRoute=" + data);
}
```

Also,in above code to access history from props, you will need to enclose your component with withRouter
like below :

```
export default withRouter(YourComponentName);
```